# Controlling procedural generation squares variant and decay

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have made a program to make squares that produce smaller squares on the top and left that are smaller then the they where made form but running into problems controlling the variant of their sizes.

The live code can be found
[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/zergRush/p85okq14/)

main function to make the squares:

```
function createCubes(maxX, maxY, minX, minY,lastColor) 
{
if (maxX - minX < 50 || maxY - minY < 50 ) 
{
  return;
}
//var decayRate = .5;
var x = getNumber(minX+50, maxX-50);
var y = getNumber(minY+50, maxY-50);
var width = maxX - x;
var height = maxY - y;
var color;
do
{
        color = getNumber(0, colors.length);
}
while(color == lastColor);
var tempCube = new Cube(color, x, y, width, height);
cubes.push(tempCube);
createCubes(maxX, y, x, minY,color);
createCubes(x, maxY,minX, y,color);

}
```

I tried increasing the min and deceasing the max values put into the getNumber function but it resulted in the squares going out of bounds.

Yes I know I called them cubes in the program.

if you need any explaining comment I will try to get to it as fast as possible.

Thanks for the Help!

Update:
I found that when subtracting the max value and setting the base chase to what I subtracted helps keep them nicer but you don't get as many.

Update:

added color and an attempt to control the squares. They still decay at an uncontrollable rate

Comment: So what is your purpose of the code? I only see a bunch of rectangles looking messy.

Comment: Well It looks messy right now because I cant control how much they vary in size. But my end goal is to make a web page decoration that will animate in the bottom right of a web page with the squares animating by changing color in a pattern.

Comment: procedural generation is just a challenge for me and I think having it bring more for my site.

Comment: Are you supposed to be using `decayRate` somewhere in your code?

Comment: I wanted to use it to control how fast the squares get smaller but could not find a way to get to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `requestAnimationFrame` as a timing loop. `rAF` automatically sends a timestamp argument that you can use to control the drawing rate (decay rate) of your rectangles.

**Here is annotated code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var rectSize=100;
var rectResizing=0.75;
var rectX=0;
var nextTime=0;
var decayDelay=500;
var decayRate=0.95;
var loopCount=0;
var labelY=150;

requestAnimationFrame(decayLoop);

function decayLoop(time){
    // wait for elapsed time
    if(time<nextTime){requestAnimationFrame(decayLoop);return;}
    // reset for nextTime
    nextTime=time+decayDelay;
    // update the decay
    decayDelay*=decayRate;
    // draw the decayed rect
    ctx.fillStyle='#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    ctx.fillRect(rectX,20,rectSize,rectSize);
    rectX+=rectSize;
    rectSize*=rectResizing;
    // display current decayDelay & rectSize
    //ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,40);
    ctx.fillStyle='black';
    ctx.fillText('Loop count: '+(loopCount++)+', RectSize: '+parseInt(rectSize)+', DecayDelay: '+decayDelay,10,labelY);
    labelY+=12;
    // request another loop
    if(rectSize>=1){
        requestAnimationFrame(decayLoop);
    }else{
        alert('End: Rect size has decayed below 1px');
    }
}
```

```css
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width=512 height=512></canvas>
```

Comment: I like what you done but I want to play with it for a bit before i check your answer

Comment: Ok so your code is great for the drawing but no the generation of the squares. I really like it makes a cool effect for drawing but I can't figure how to get the squares to branch like mine do. I can can get your in the bottom right and to spawn them going left and up at the same time but not  filling in like mine do.

Comment: I used your draw function with my code and it made a cool effect have a look [live code](https://jsfiddle.net/zergRush/p85okq14/)